# Is $\alpha^{\beta}=2^{\beta}$ for all infinite cardinalities $\alpha, \beta$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is $\alpha^{\beta}=2^{\beta}$ for all infinite cardinalities $\alpha, \beta$?

I was wondering about this since I've encountered examples of times where this holds, but I can't seem to prove it myself and I'm pretty skeptical that it's true in general.

Can anyone shed light on this please? What are the limitations of this?

Thanks!

Comment: My discrete math professor told us when we were freshmen "If you tried to prove something, and you couldn't, and then you found out it's wrong; then you did a good job not lying to yourself." (Although he said that on the continuing complaints that the exercise sheets are plagued with typos and mistakes...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not at all. For example let $\alpha=2^{2^\beta}$ then we have: $$\alpha^\beta=\left(2^{2^\beta}\right)^\beta=2^{2^\beta\cdot\beta}=2^{2^\beta}=\alpha.$$

If $2<\alpha\leq 2^\beta$ then $2^\beta\leq\alpha^\beta\leq2^\beta$ and we have equality. Otherwise $2^\beta<\alpha$ and $(2^\beta)^\beta=2^\beta<\alpha\leq\alpha^\beta$.

Comment: I'm not sure what your counterexample is. Can you give your $\alpha$ and $\beta$ explicitly?

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: I don't see the counterexample either.
edit: Okay. :)

Comment: @Adar: There is one now.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for point this out! :-)

Comment: Thanks Asaf!
Alright, so do you have any idea under what circumstances this might be true?

Comment: @Adar: I added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared things up for me, I appreciate it.

Comment: By the way Asaf, how do you justify raising the inequality $2<\alpha<2^{\beta}$ to the power $\beta$?

Comment: @Adar: What do you mean? I assume that $\alpha$ satisfies these conditions. Cardinal exponentiation is weakly-increasing. That means that $\kappa<\lambda$ then $\kappa^\mu\leq\lambda^\mu$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!!